# Unable to inspect element from appium inspector for android device on Mac PC

Tags: appium, appium-android

Unable to inspect element from appium inspector for android device on Mac PC.

Mac: 10.13
Appium: 1.7.2
Appium Inspector : 1.5.3
Android Device Simulator: Pixel-2
Android Version: 8.0

I am able to inspect element for iOS  (iPhone device) for the same application, but unable to inspect the element in android.

When I click on inspect icon of appium dmg of 1.5.3 (in Terminal i run appium 1.7.2), it launches the device but i dont see anything in appium inspector tool.

Please help, I have tried UIAutomateviewer as well, but since my application dont have most the ID's for most of the elements so I need XPATH in my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by downgrading my Android version to 6.0.

However please let me know if any one of you have solution for the latest android versions

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong but trying to help:

Try uiautomatorviewer if your application does not have id then certainly can use resource-id as id

Or can use XCUI test 
Very well explained here:
http://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Finding+Elements+on+XCUITest+devices?src=contextnavpagetreemode

Also, this webpage explain how to fetch xpath
https://bitbar.com/appium-tip-13-use-inspector-or-uiautomatorviewer-for-ui-element-inspection/

XCUI explained in detail
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BgkVp0v3BM

Also can try Macaca inspector if you have not tried before, this worked for me with appium 1.6 
https://gopekannan.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/macaca-inspector-for-apple-mac/

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, i will look into these and let you know

Answer (score 2):

first of all you need to set the desired capabilities in the new session window for inspecting elements of the android app.

the three imp DC's are -
1. app -> add the path of .apk file
2. deviceName-> to get the device name, type adb devices in terminal and get the device name from there 
3. PlatformName -> android

start the session. 
soon you will be able to inspect the elements. 
If your facing any issues, let me know i'll be happy to help.